# Add a button within a ScrollView

Tags: android, button, radio-button, scrollview

I need some help I have a scrollview that shows some question with radio buttons and I want to add a button when the user reaches the last question and I want this button to be available only after the user has selected an answer to all the questions.

This is my code so far but it is not displaying anything. I can display the questions without the button but I want to display the button too.

```
String countryName[] = { "India", "Pakistan", "China", "Nepal",
   "Bangladesh" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);

      for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)       
      {
       //create text button
       TextView title = new TextView(this);
       title.setText("Question Number:" + k);
       title.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
       mLinearLayout.addView(title);

       // create radio button
       final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
       RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
       rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
       {
        rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setText(countryName[i]);       
       }
       mLinearLayout.addView(rg);}

      ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);

      Button btn = new Button(this);
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams blp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      btn.setLayoutParams(blp);
      btn.setText("Click Me");

      mLinearLayout.addView(scroll);
      mLinearLayout.addView(btn);

      setContentView(mLinearLayout);
}
```

The XML file:

```
 <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">       
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Continue" />

 </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: first disable the button.after user answer the last question enable the button.

Comment: that is a good idea but I am not displaying the questions nor the buttons ... can you help me with that?

Comment: please explain clearly. from your question am assume.after user answer the all question then only you going to display the button am right.

Comment: no i want the button to be there but unavailable and when all the questions are answered the button to become available.

Comment: you means button be there not in active or to hide the button.

Comment: the button should be inactive not invisible

Comment: k.if you set button as invisible means automatically the button is in inactive state only.

Answer (score 0):

```
    mLinearLayout.addView(btn);
          scroll.addView(mLinearLayout);
setContentView(scroll);
```

Comment: Nope this did not help at all now the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

You should place your LinearLayout inside the ScrollView, because  ScrollView is a container and its children are scrollable. Also, set the ScrollView as the activity's content view and define its layout params.

```
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
scrollView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
scroll.addView(mLinearLayout);
setContentView(scroll);
```

Comment: Could you please post the XML where you defined the LinearLayout "R.id.linear1"?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found the right way to do it! The easiest way is to fix the XML file and add a LinearLayout within the LinearLayout and put the questions within the inner LinearLayout and the button in the outside LinearLayout.

Here is the trick:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linear1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="2.87"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
 </LinearLayout>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="2.87"
     android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```